# How to do GridView RowUpdating event

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to perform an update action in GRID VIEW control in asp.net.

My code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t1 = new TextBox();

    t1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt16(HiddenField1)].Cells[3].Controls[0];

}
```

When I run, I get the error as "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField' to type 'System.IConvertible"

Can anyone help me in suggesting a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to use the .value property, as in `HiddenField1.Value`:

```
t1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[int.Parse(HiddenField1.Value)].Cells[3].Controls[0];
```

It looks like, before, you were trying to convert a `HiddenField` control into an `int`, which isn't going to work.  Also, you can just use `int.Parse` to convert the value stored in the `HiddenField` into an `int`.

Comment: Thank you very much Jadarne. It is a silly error, but as I am developing my first web application, hope it got stuck with this error

Comment: @user1185691 Glad to help!  No worries, we all started somewhere =)  If this helped you, you can click the grey up arrow to vote it up, or accept it with the check mark: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)?